# Complilation Issue

Tags: visual-studio, gcc, mingw

c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:C:\Program Files (x86)\Sublime Text 3\CP\input.txt: file format not recognized; **treating as linker script**
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:C:\Program Files (x86)\Sublime Text 3\CP\input.txt:1: syntax error
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
[Finished in 0.5s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: g++ -std=c++14 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Sublime Text 3\CP\input.txt" -o "C:\Program Files (x86)\Sublime Text 3\CP/input" && "C:\Program Files (x86)\Sublime Text 3\CP/input"]

Comment: Try: https://stackoverflow.com/tour and https://stackoverflow.com/help

Answer (score 0):

In the command line:

```
g++ -std=c++14 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Sublime Text 3\CP\input.txt" -o "C:\Program Files (x86)\Sublime Text 3\CP/input"
```

You're trying to compile `input.txt` as if it's a C++ source file.
If it is C++ you should give it a proper extension, but more probably it isn't C++ but somehow you're trying to compile it...